# Inherit from internal SoundEffectInstance, no constructors defined

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, xna

I'm trying to create a new class `FadableSoundEffectInstance`, that inherits from `SoundEffectInstance`.

My `FadableSoundEffectInsance` will allow `SoundEffectInstances` to be easlily faded in and out, however after finishing the class, I was rewarded with this lovely error here:

`The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffectInstance' has no constructors defined`

After a while of research and digging into the XNA source, I found this.

```
internal SoundEffectInstance(SoundEffect parentEffect, bool fireAndForget)
{
...
}
```

So it does have a constructor, but I cannot access it.

How can I work around this to be able to create my class?

Note for people who have not used XNA before, you DO NOT create a new class with `blah = new SoundEffectInstance` instead you load a `SoundEffect` and use the method `CreateInstance()`. Also, `SoundEffect` is a sealed class. Also, adding a constructor to my new class will throw the same error, but for `SoundEffectInstance` instead.

Here is my relevant code incase you need to look in depth

FadableSoundEffectInstance

```
    public sealed class FadableSoundEffectInstance : SoundEffectInstance
    {
        public float FadeSpeed = .01f;
        public AudioFadeState FadeState = AudioFadeState.Normal;

        public void FadeOut()
        {
            //Logic
        }
        public void FadeIn()
        {
            //Logic
        }
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //Logic
        }
    }
```

And an extension method so I can call `SoundEffect.CreateFadableInstance()`

```
    public static FadableSoundEffectInstance CreateFadableInstance(this SoundEffect soundEffect)
    {
        return (FadableSoundEffectInstance)soundEffect.CreateInstance();
    }
```

Comment: BTW: `SoundEffectInstance` is not sealed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Correct, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a `SoundEffectInstance` to the class instead of inheriting it, it's probably not the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
public SoundEffectInstance BaseInstance;
```

And changing my extension method to this:

```
    public static FadableSoundEffectInstance CreateFadableInstance(this SoundEffect soundEffect)
    {
        return new FadableSoundEffectInstance(soundEffect);
    }
```

And my class to handle the sound effect, turn it into a `SoundEffectInstance`, and do any initialization the class may need

```
    public FadableSoundEffectInstance(SoundEffect soundEffect, float fadeSpeed = .1f)
    {
        BaseInstance = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
        BaseInstance.Volume = 0;
        FadeSpeed = fadeSpeed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not unique.
You don't have access to the constructor, so you can't create a derived class. This is the same whether you use XNA or not.

If you want to use your new sound effect directly, you can create a pseudo-decorator, that takes in the actual `SoundEffectInstance` and wraps it.

However, this doesn't help you if you want to pass your sound effect to XNA methods that want a `SoundEffectInstance`.

Comment: The problem of interoperating with XNA methods is easy enough to address:  just write an implicit conversion operator that returns the underlying `SoundEffectInstance`.

Comment: @ColeCampbell: And how would that help? It would no longer be one that fades.

Comment: Do you expect XNA's internal code to call the new methods on the fading sound effect that make it fade?  Perhaps I've misunderstood the point you were trying to make.  By the time you get to an XNA method that requires a `SoundEffectInstance`, the fading aspect of it is irrelevant.  My suggestion is purely a matter of convenience, saving you the step of having to expose the underlying `SoundEffectInstance` through a property.